Unable to Retrieve Field Types Using SOAP API in Polarion Integration
I am currently working on integrating Polarion with my application using the SOAP API. As part of this integration, I need to retrieve the fields and their types from Polarion.
I have already assigned types to the fields in the Polarion application, but when I attempt to retrieve these fields via the API, I can only fetch the field names, and their types are either null or not included in the response.
Here is the relevant code snippet I’m using:
var trackerService = new TrackerWebServiceClient();
var customFields = trackerService.getDefinedCustomFieldTypes("projectName", "typeID");

foreach (var field in customFields)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"ID: {field.id}");
  Console.WriteLine($"Type: {field.Type}");
}

Issue:
The field. Type property does not return any value or type information for the fields.
What I’ve Tried:
Verified that types are assigned correctly in the Polarion UI.
Checked the API response for any additional properties related to type.
Tested with different field contexts (e.g., projectID and tyepID:issue).
Questions:

Is there a specific method or API call required to fetch the type of a field?
Are there any additional configurations needed in Polarion to expose the type information via the API?
Could this be related to permissions or a specific version of the Polarion API?

Environment:

Polarion Version: [Add Version]
API Used: SOAP (TrackerWebService)
Language: C# (.NET Framework [Version])

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
